# In UDK, how and where do I script to enable Alt-F4 for exiting game?

Tags: udk

By default, Alt-F4 does not work in a UDK game.

How would I go about adding unreal script to cause the game to exit to desktop upon Alt-F4?

## Update

This is what I've tried:

```
; Primary default bindings
.Bindings=(Name="F4",Command="exit",Alt=True)   
.Bindings=(Name="F10",Command="ToggleInventory")
.Bindings=(Name="SpaceBar",Command="GBA_Jump")
```

Answer (score 2):

That would be your DefaultInput.ini. If you add something along the lines of `+Bindings=(Name="F4",Command="exit",Alt=True)`, that should do the trick. The next time you run the game, the UDKInput.ini will be rebuilt using a combination of DefaultInput.ini and the BaseInput.ini in Engine\Config.

Comment: Please see my update above. I have tried starting the line with "." or "+", but both do not work. I included the other commands in my update above to show where within DefaultInput.ini I have inserted the line for Alt-F4

Comment: A little further down in the file, F4 is being re-bound to the command "Playersonly". Comment that line out and you should be good-to-go!